# Removing Non Business Days from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column containing dates associated with the data. I'm looking to remove all rows of data that are not business days (accounting for bank holidays as well). What are the best ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

When we check the holiday we can always create the holiday list then use `isin`

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar
holidays = calendar.holidays(start='2000-01-01', end='2020-12-31')
m = df['date'].isin(holidays)
df1 = df[~m].copy()
```

Comment: instantiate class calendar() before calling the holidays() function, otherwise TypeError: holidays() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. Full code: holidays = calendar().holidays(start='1993-01-01', end='2030-12-31')